# ColdFusion cfqueryparam CFSQLTypes for MySQL 5.x

Tags: mysql, coldfusion, coldfusion-11, coldfusion-2016

I've been looking for a reference table for the CFSQLType argument of the cfqueryparam (or cfscript variants) that includes MySQL 5.x datatypes.

I have been able to find this table at Adobe:

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-tags/tags-p-q/cfqueryparam.html

But it only includes information for JDBC, DB2, Oracle, and MSSQL.  I also get the feel that this and many of the adobe sourced documentation is hovering around CF 9/10.  They used to have separate documentation areas for specific versions but I'm not sure if they are available anymore.

I've found the cfqueryparam tag on cfdocs.org, but it doesn't include a table or reference for any database systems.

https://cfdocs.org/cfqueryparam

Some of the MySQL 5.x datatypes will match up consistently that other database platforms have; a varchar is a CF_SQL_VARCHAR, etc.

MySQL has some unique types like GEOMETRY, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, LINESTRING, MULTILINESTRING, MULTIPOINT, MULTIPOLYGON, POINT, and POLYGON.  It also has some other datatypes that I can make assumptions on like JSON, ENUM, and SET being CF_SQL_VARCHAR.  Other datatypes like MEDIUMINT, MEDIUMTEXT, TINYTEXT, etc. I've made some guesses on as well.

Does anyone know if there is a reference out there that maps all of these MySQL 5.x datatypes to cfqueryparam CFSQLType arguments?

Options:
1. create a table with every datatype, query it, and view the CF metadata to determine how CF binds to the columns.
2. create a table with every datatype and use cfdbinfo on it to see what types are returned for the columns.

I'm not sure if either of those options will return useful info, but that's what I'm going to try next if documentation doesn't exist.

Comment: The geometric values can usually be converted to JSON / GeoJSON

Comment: `MySQL has some unique types` Unless those are in the JDBC specs, I wouldn't expect there to be any cfsqltypes for them. CFSqltypes tend to be vanilla and usually mirror the generic [JDBC types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html),  `documentation is hovering around CF 9/10` True, but there haven't been too many changes in jdbc, afaik. so I'd guess they're converted into an existing type (object/OTHER, etc...) where possible.

Comment: This is old but might help: http://cfsearching.blogspot.com/2010/01/cfqueryparam-matrix-for-mysql-5.html